# Preserving special chars in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, carriage-return, linefeed

I've an xml string stored in the db table with line feed characters.
In my C# 3.5 program, I load and manipulate it using Linq to xml and then show it as a string in the textbox control on the UI form.

I need to indent this xml as well as preserve line feeds/carriage return while showing it in the UI.

Am able to indent it but how do I preserve LF/CR chars in the xml??

Here's the sample C# code:

```
    XElement rootNode = CreateRootNode();
    XElement testXmlNode = XElement.Parse(xmlFromDbWithLFChars);

    rootNode.Add(testXmlNode );

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
     Indent = true
    };

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
    {
     rootNode.WriteTo(writer);
    }
    xmlString  = builder.ToString();   

    xmlString = xmlString.Replace("&#xD;", Environment.NewLine); //Doesnt work

    xmlString = xmlString.Replace("&#xA;", Environment.NewLine);  //Doesnt work

//Heres how the xml should look like in the UI control:
 <TestNode
             name="xyz"
             Id="12">
             <Children>
                  <Child name="abc" location="p" />
             </Children>
    </TestNode>
```

Comment: By preserve, you mean that you want the XML new-lines to act like new-lines in the UI?

Comment: One more question: when you say "// doesn't work", you mean it shows two new-lines, or none at all?

Comment: Beemer, it does not show any new line in the xml in UI.

Comment: Can you give an example? Like, what is the input value contained in `xmlFromDbWithLFChars` variable?

Comment: +5? This question is a mess. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with C# or XML as much as it has to do with UI controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to set the settings of formatting on the XmlWriter, so change your row:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() 
    { 
     Indent = true 
    };
```

To something like this:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() 
    { 
     Indent = true,
     IndentChars = "\n",
     NewLineOnAttributes = true
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Almund!.The only thing I had missed in my original approach was using "NewLineOnAttributes = true" and this seems to work great!!!

Comment: Easy to miss, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your responses. Finally,I could get this working.

My approach does not use Linq2Xml/SAX parser.Am generating the xml using StringBuilder and showing it in the UI in a winforms Rich textbox control.Now,I can see line-feeds as it is in the UI.

Comment: you should add the solution you used as an answer.

Comment: "generating the xml using StringBuilder" - I'm sorry but there is no way in hell this is correct. XML is not string data, attempting to treat it as such whether that's regex parsing or stringbuilder assembling lacks rigour, is brittle for maintenance and is extremely prone to human error.

Comment: Annakata, what u r saying is true, but,unfortunately I cant give the same justification to business....since I didnt want to go the StringBuilder way knowing that it wud be fragile code, I first tried with Linq2API, SAX and DOM parser...but cudnt get the desired formatted  output.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you convert an XML document to a string and start manipulating the string, you should think to yourself, "Self, I am doing something wrong."  I'm not certain from your description if that's true, but I bet it is.

If the whitespace in the XML you're pulling from the database is significant, you want to preserve it when you parse it into your `XElement`.  To do this, use the overload of `XElement.Parse` that does this, e.g.:

```
XElement testXmlNode = XElement.Parse(xmlFromDbWithLFChars, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

When you do this, the parser will leave whitespace characters in the parsed `XElement` document's text nodes exactly where they were in the original string.  `XmlWriter` doesn't mess with existing whitespace in text nodes (though it will add new whitespace if you tell it to indent), so this should get you what you want.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your response...but this approach does not to work for me...i still cant see line feeds in the xml in textarea in UI .

Comment: When you say "textarea", do you mean an HTML TEXTAREA?  Because new lines in a TEXTAREA element are indicated by CR/LF pairs.  If you just have LF characters in the XML text, they won't render as newlines in a TEXTAREA.

Comment: Its a textbox control on a .Net Winform.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the fact that you can't see line feeds in the textarea doesn't mean they're not present in the XML.  If you just send a string like `this\nis\na\ntest` to the UI, does it display with newlines?

Comment: I had tried that earlier....no, it doesnt show newlines in the textbox.....Thanks.

Comment: Then this problem doesn't have anything to do with XML, does it?

Comment: daft question but is the text box multiline enabled? and does it accept carriage returns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlReader to preserve the new lines and everything.. here is sample code that worked fine for me when testing:

```
System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create("XML URI here");
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
while (reader.Read())
{
    sb.Append(reader.ReadOuterXml());
}
reader.Close();
txtXML.InnerText = sb.ToString();
txtXML.Visible = true;
```

In my test I loaded XML file, you can load your manipulated XML string.

Comment: thanks for your response...Do i need to use XmlReaderSettings object here to preserve formatting?

Comment: @user40907 nope, you can use the code as-is just load your own XML as pure text.

Comment: @user40907 can you post code how you set the textbox data with the XML? maybe I can reproduce then solve this.

Comment: am just setting the textbox's text property with xml string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making sure the textbox is in multiline mode and [accepts carriage return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn.aspx)?

```
public void CreateMyMultilineTextBox() {
   // Create an instance of a TextBox control.
   TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

   // Set the Multiline property to true.
   textBox1.Multiline = true;
   // Add vertical scroll bars to the TextBox control.
   textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
   // Allow the RETURN key to be entered in the TextBox control.
   textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
   // Allow the TAB key to be entered in the TextBox control.
   textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
   // Set WordWrap to true to allow text to wrap to the next line.
   textBox1.WordWrap = true;
   // Set the default text of the control.
   textBox1.Text = "Welcome!";
 }
```